# When and why one should make the static constructor as private?

Tags: c#, constructor

I know the difference between static constructor and private constructor and when to use them. But, when  should one make the static constructor as private and what is the advantage of doing this?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is there any programming language, other than IL, that allows you to not make it private?

Comment: No other language 'afaik' (in .net) allows you to not make them private.  That rule is forced by the compiler, which every .Net framework language relies on.  Also, I can not think of a single reason one would ever need to make one public.

If you need to be able to run it's initialize logic again, use a static method called Initialize that the static constructor calls.  Users can reinvoke the Initialize Method.

Answer (score 2):

Access modifiers are not allowed on static constructors in C#, they are (in a way) always public, meaning that the framework can always access them to perform type-specific initialization. Adding `public` or `private` to a static constructor will not compile.

A `private` constructor is always an instance private constructor, which is a different thing  and is most commonly used when creating singletons, to prevent explicit instantiation of the class through user code.

Comment: Note they are neither public nor private from a client-code point of view. You can never invoke a static constructor yourself, so the public vs private is not relevant in this case. Additionally, you don't actually have any control over when the CLR will decide to call it (which should certainly always happen before you try to instantiate it your self, or access any static members of that class).

Answer (score 1):

The static constructor should always be private.

**Why?**

Generally, a static constructor is called by the framework even before the first instance of that class is created. This creates one single instance of that type readily available for usage.

However, if the constructor is not private, it means that other objects can create the instance too. This could possible cause unexpected behaviors.

So, the static constructor should always be private.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *"if the constructor is not private, it means that other objects can create the instance too"*. Are you talking about the static or instance constructor? If you're talking about instance constructor, I don't see how making it public could cause unexpected behaviors. And a static constructor cannot be called by other object, so I also don't get it.

Comment: I meant the static constructor. Apologies for the loss of clarity

Comment: -1. The static constructor *can only be private* or it will not compile. The static constructor does not create an instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `private` keyword doesn't actually do anything in C#. By default everything is already `private`, except non-nested types which are `internal` because they can't be `private`.

These days I never use the `private` keyword, it's just noise.

Note: This is only true for C#. In Visual Basic the default visibility isn't sane and you'll want to explicitly use `Private` where appropriate.

Comment: _These days I never use the private keyword_ I have totally opposite behaviour :) I use `private` as much as possible.

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, I still make as much as possible private. I just don't see the need for the keyword itself. Think of it this way: leaving it private is free, making it public requires typing something.

Comment: I type private because it promotes better code readability in dev teams with code reviewers and QA people.

E.g. my QA guy is a java guy going over my C#.  He doesn't know that C# defaults them to private.  As such it's a good thing I marked them as private visually because he understands that, it's obvious.

I'm a firm believer that as much information should be able to be acquired as possible by just looking at the code.  E.g. a private method should be marked private, and it should have a name that is named in such a way that's it's obvious what the method does.  I'm huge on regions to.

Comment: Although an interesting point, I fail to see how this answers the OPs question, i.e. *[..] when should one make the static constructor as private [..]*

Comment: @JonathanAllen: for someone who is used to using  VB.NET it's better to make everything explicit. Otherwise it's likely that you eventually forget the default accessibility of the current project's language.

Comment: @Ryios The solution for ignorance is not coddling, it is education. If they can't understand something as simple as private-by-default, then there is no way they are going to understand async/await.